# Can't publish Open Graph actions - error 2500

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Can you please help me with this problem that I am facing last days.

I am trying to use Open Graph on our videos. [This is a link for an example page.](http://www.101greatgoals.com/gvideos/individual-highlights-zinedine-zidane-real-madrid-legends-3-manchester-united-legends-2/)

It's working on Facebook Graph API and also on a test page that sits on our server but is not part of the site.

When I try that on our system, I am getting this error:

> {"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}

When I check that page on the debugger tool, I get this error:

> Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http://www.101greatgoals.com/gvideos/stunning-setplay-juan-roman-riquelme-boca-juniors-vs-deportivo-merlo/' of type 'video.other' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

There is a "TEST" button below the videos in order to run this action.

Didn't find a solution for fixing it yet.
Can some please advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Object Invalid Value: Object at URL 'http://www.101greatgoals.com/gvideos/stunning-setplay-juan-roman-riquelme-boca-juniors-vs-deportivo-merlo/' of type 'video.other' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

What part of that don’t you understand …?

In your page, you have `<meta property='og:image' content='' />` (not in the first block of meta elements, but some way further down) – and an empty URL is not readable for Facebook …